# Meaning of "Sleeping" process

Tags: linux, shell

What does really mean "Sleeping" referring to a process? I started a duplication of a MySQL database with PhpMyAdmin and then, looking at process with "top" Linux command the only running process is "top" while mysqld is "Sleeping" (S) but consuming 50 %CPU and 15 %MEM.
In the "The Linux Command Line: a complete introduction" it is explained as "Sleeping. The process is not running; rather, it is waiting for an event, such as a keystroke or network packet." but mysqld process is running by itself without waiting for an event, and same situation for all other events.

Comment: A process might have been sleeping right when it was checked with top, but then woke up and did some work and went back to sleep again.  If it is using 50% cpu, it could be sleeping half the time.

Comment: I understand my question was marked as duplicate but could anyone indicate me the link to answered (already solved) question, please?